# php 'salesPrice' to $price

Tags: php, joomla, calculator

My Joomla and virtuemart have a product price `salesPrice` that is shown by this:

```
echo $this->currency->createPriceDiv ('salesPrice', 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_SALESPRICE', $this->product->prices);
```

Now I need to convert `salesPrice` to `$customprice` so I can calculate it in code like this:

```
<?php 

$customprice = ('salesPrice');
$cijenaraw = str_replace(' Kn','',$customprice);
$cijenaraw2 = str_replace('.','',$customprice);
$cijenaraw3 = str_replace(',','.',$cijenaraw2);
$dicscijena = ($cijenaraw3 / 100) * 92;
$novacijena = round($dicscijena, 2);
echo '<p style="margin-top:10px;color: #FF7800;"><strong>*Cijena: '. number_format($custompricefinal, 2, ',', '.') .' HRK</strong></p>';

endif; 

?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: You're not actually asking anything. We don't know what you mean by "convert".

Comment: I,m new to php so as far i understand 'salesPrice' is returning previously defined price per product, i need to add custom discount in code that calulates 8% discount in all products.

Comment: When i add code like above it keeps returnin 0,00 as result

Comment: I don't see `$custompricefinal` being defined anywhere... And what do you expect `$customprice = ('salesPrice')` to do? I think you forgot to add a function name there, or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$customprice = ('salesPrice');` can't give you any value.

If you are using the script in the product details page you have to add:

> $customprice = $this->product->prices['salesPrice'];

If it is in the category browse page:

> $customprice = $product->prices['salesPrice'];

Now `$customprice` would have the sales price that you could make calculations.

Comment: Thanks emmanuel the first one was just what i needed.

Comment: Nice to hear that, you are welcome!